# How to change the value of an object in all levels of keys?

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

I want to update all password values from an object in all object levels:

```
let obj = {
  user: {
    name: 'u1', 
    password: 'do not show me'
  },
  subUsers: [
    {
      name: 'u2', 
      password: 'do not show me as well'
    }
  ],
  whereverLevel : {
    password: 'please, hide me too'
  }
}

updateDeeply(obj, 'password', '********') //mutates obj and changes all password values in all object levels.
```

Is there an API method like lodash `_.set(...)`?

Comment: What have you tried? A recursive search would be trivial.

Comment: I'm looking for an api like lodash and didn't find it

Comment: That would almost surely be overkill. This would literally just be a iteration over each key/val pair, recursing into each val that's a map, and replacing any vals that have a "password" key. I think you need to narrow this question down, as it's quite broad right now.

Comment: Why would you have passwords as plain english anyways? You should be encrypting them and then this question seems moot.

Comment: If this is absolutely needed you could try converting your obj to json string, doing a regex of 'password:' and then doing it that way, but encrypting passwords seems like the real answer.

Comment: It's a good workaround @jdmdevdotnet! But I want to know an already implemented API.

Comment: I want to ensure data security to logs!

Comment: I don't think my solution is a workaround, it's the valid way to do things. You should never have passwords as plain english. First of all, that's horrible security, and second your users probably wouldn't appreciate you knowing all their passwords. they should be encrypted, therefore this question is moot. But good luck, I guess :)

Comment: Again, you have passwords in plain english. They should be encrypted, whether thats in your DB (where they should be encrypted) or when the user creates a password. it should be immediately encrypted. That way you can't just go in your DB and look up someone's password thats likely their password to other things. Horrible security storing passwords in plain english. I find it a little ironic you're worried about security, yet you store passwords in plain english in DB.

Comment: I'm not storing it! It's only an example!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple recursive solution, handling objects and arrays, mutating input –

```
function deepReplace ( x, targetKey, replaceWith ) {
    if ( Array.isArray( x ) ) {
        x.forEach( x => deepReplace( x, targetKey, replaceWith ) );
    } else if ( typeof x === 'object' ) {
        for ( var key in x ) {
            if ( key === targetKey ) x[ key ] = replaceWith;
            if ( typeof x[ key ] === 'object' ) {
                 deepReplace( x[ key ], targetKey, replaceWith );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 function* deepIterate(obj) {
  yield obj;
  for(const value of Object.values(obj)) 
   if(typeof value === "object")
     yield* deepIterate(value);
 }
```

Which can be used as:

```
for(const el of deepIterate(obj))
  if(el.password) el.password = "******";
```

Comment: This is nice! I am confused on how exactly this works when the value is an array... could you elaborate?

Comment: if someone is in doubt that this is working, [click here](http://jsbin.com/jesidepoma/edit?console)

Comment: @JonasW. This solution is avaliable in babel transpiler? Or just in nodejs?

Comment: This is ES6, so you should use Babel if you wanna support IE and Netscape :) Everything else (nodejs too) should support it (except you use a version from the middle age)

Answer (score 1):

```
function updateKeys(keyName, value, input) {
  Object.keys(input).map(key => {
    if (key === keyName) {
      input[key] = value;
    } else if (Array.isArray(input[key])) {
      input[key].map(e => updateKeys(keyName, value, e));
    } else if (input[key] && input[key][keyName]) {
      input[key][keyName] = value;
    }
  });
}
```

https://repl.it/repls/AveragePalegreenFrontend

Answer (score 0):

```
let obj = {
    user: {
        name: 'u1',
        password: 'do not show me'
    },
    subUsers: [
        {
            name: 'u2',
            password: 'do not show me as well'
        }
    ],
    whereverLevel: {
        password: 'please, hide me too'
    }
};

// Use recursion.
function updateDeeply(obj, key, value) {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (_key) {
        // Note that Object.keys() works on arrays as well.
        if (_key === key) {
            obj[_key] = value;
        } else if (typeof obj[_key] === 'object' || Array.isArray(obj[_key])) {
            // Make recursive call.
            updateDeeply(obj[_key], key, value);
        }
    });
}

updateDeeply(obj, 'password', 'replace');

console.log(obj);
```